# How do you save a persistent session with a cookie in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, session, cookies, cgi, persistence

All I'm looking for is something very simple.  I want to check if the client has my cookie in their browser.  If so then to load the last session ID from the cookie and access the session from the server side.  If not I want to create the server side session and store the session id to the cookie.

So my question is two parts.  What parts of the session code/variable/ID is relevant to retrieve it in the future?  And what's the simple method for achieving a continuous session via cookie/session?

I am not using rails.  It's a standard CGI script.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'cgi'
require 'cgi/session'
require 'cgi/session/pstore'

cgi = CGI.new("html4")

# !! TODO !! if cookie has "session_id" then open sess from "session_id"

sess = CGI.Session.new( cgi,
    'database_manager' => CGI::Session::PStore,  # use PStore
    'session_key' => '_rb_sess_id',              # custom session key
    'session_expires' => Time.now + 30 * 60,     # 30 minute timeout
    'prefix' => 'pstore_sid_')  

if sess.has_key? "friend_list"
    @friend_list = sess['friend_list']
    sess['access_count'] += 1
else
    @friend_list = JSON.parse( IO.read( "fbget.json" ) )
    sess['friend_list'] = @friend_list
    sess['access_count'] = 1
end
```

---

I wanted to save the json list on the server side via a session instance.  I figure putting that in a cookie would be a very bad security mistake.

Through my searching online I haven't found any non-rails info on saving session access info via the cookie.  Only how to use each individually.

Comment: It's really messy to use CGI in this day and age compared to something simple like [writing a Rack handler](http://m.onkey.org/ruby-on-rack-1-hello-rack). Usually small applications like this are best implemented in [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) which is extremely stripped down compared to Rails.

Comment: Unfortunately the server I use doesn't give me much liberty over running an alternate server service or having alternate ports.  I rag patch it just to use rubygems.

Comment: Considering a high-quality VPS costs as little as [$5 a month](https://www.digitalocean.com/) you shouldn't have to subject yourself to the legacy world of shared hosting. There's also services like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) that have a free tier to prototype your application, and possibly even run it through a beta stage. Heroku in particular makes it super easy to deploy a Rack-compatible application.